# Ubuntu quickly warning

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, ubuntu-12.04, glade, canonical-quickly

I just created "jotty" the tutorial application using quickly. It works fine, but I get the following warnings:

```
$ quickly run
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning:
       g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `Window' 
       can't be set after construction
Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning:
       g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `AppWindow' 
       can't be set after construction
Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```

I am running ubuntu 12.04 . Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Open your /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py and make change (line 391)

from:

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, type=Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL, **kwds):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```

to:

```
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, type=Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL, **kwds):
        # type is a construct-only property; if it is already set (e. g. by
        # GtkBuilder), do not try to set it again and just ignore it
        try:
            self.get_property('type')
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self, **kwds)
        except TypeError:
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)
```